# Want to show alert box with message if I skip to input

Tags: javascript, html

[Error codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybU3s.png)I created the signup form page and If I skip entering the information, I want to make an alert box with javascript. But in JavaScript, it's showing the errors and doesn't show any alert if I skip. Is there any way to fix it? I will provide error codes with screenshot. Also, I want to do that If I click submit, I want to show ***Your request is successful*** box.

```js
function validateForm() {
   var name = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
   var email = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
   var birthday = document.forms["myForm"]["birthday"].value;

   var interest = document.forms["myForm"]["shopping"].value;
   if (name == "") {
      alert("Name must be filled out");
      return false;
   }

   if (email == "") {
      alert("Email must be filled out");
      return false;
   }
   if (birthday == "") {
      alert("Fill your birthday please");
      return false;
   }
   if (shopping == "1") {
      alert("Select your interested thing to do");
      return false;
   }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Busy Bee Florist</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" a href="css/style.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="containers">
      <header>
         <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
      </header>
      <nav>
         <div class="navbar">
            <a href="sign.html">Sign Up For Special Deals!"</a>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            <a href="account.html">Account</a>
            <a href="cart.html">Cart</a>
            <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
               <button class="dropbtn">Colors
               <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
               </button>
               <div class="dropdown-content">
                  <a href="white.html">White</a>
                  <a href="red.html">Red</a>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
               <button class="dropbtn">Occasions
               </button>
               <div class="dropdown-content">
                  <a href="congratulations.html">Congratulations</a>
                  <a href="generic.html">Generic</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </nav>
      <form></form>
      <form name="myForm" action="action_page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post"></form>
      <div class="container">
         <h1>Busy Bee Florist</h1>
         <h4> Please Fill Up In the Form</h4>
         <form>
            <fieldset>
               <legend>Personal Information:</legend>
               Full Name: <input type="text" style="margin-left: 18px;" name="name" placeholder="Your Name"><br><br>
               Email: <input type="email" style="margin-left: 51px;" placeholder="example@gmail.com" name="email"><br><br>
               Date of birth: <input type="date" name="birthday">
            </fieldset>
            <br>
            Which special offers you interest most?<br><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="shopping" value="Shopping"> Lemon Meringue Pie <br><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="shopping" value="Dining"> Respberry Cake <br><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="shopping" value="Dancing"> Bluebarry Muffins<br><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="shopping" value="caramelslice"> Caramel Slice <br><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="shopping" value="cheeryripeslice">Cheery Ripe Slice <br><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="shopping" value="chocolatechip">Chocolate Chip Muffin<br><br>
            <div class="test3"><b>Terms and Condition</b><font color="red"></font></div>
            <div class="test3"> <input type="radio" name="TC" value="agree" >I Agree</div>
            <div class="test3"> <input type="radio" name="TC" value="disagree">I Disagree</div>
            <br><br>
            <div class="w">
               <p>Please provide any additional feedbacks:- </p>
               <br><br>
               <textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="45" placeholder="Please Type Here...."></textarea>
               <br><br>
            </div>
            <br><br>
            <div id="q">
               <button class="btn-submit" value="Submit Reservation" type="submit"> Submit </button>
               <button class="btn-reset" value="Clear Input" type="reset"> Clear Input</button>
            </div>
         </form>
      </div>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"it's showing the errors"* - And what are "the errors"?

Comment: `shopping ` is also not declared on your js code. I think you meant `interest`

Comment: You should not assume that every user will fill out a form in "linear" fashion. I might f.e. not _have_ my bank details at hand right now, so before I go into the next room to fetch them, I might want to proceed with filling out fields further down, the values for which I know ... IMHO you will not be improving the UX here, but create something that will _annoy_ a lot of users.

Comment: Please check you code carefully before you ask a question... the JS code you provided is related to `myForm` form, not the second form. You have two forms there.

Comment: @David I just updated.

Comment: @trasces: Where are you running this code that `document` and `alert` are not defined?  This is code that should be executed on a web page in the context of a web browser.  What are you doing with it?

Comment: Please check you code carefully before you ask a question... the JS code you provided is related to `myForm` form, not the second form. You have two forms there. You need to sort that out. And secondly, inside your KS, there's `interest` not shopping.. that also needs sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

Let's perform some clean up to your HTML code first.

You have this in your form declaration

```
<form></form>
<form name="myForm" action="action_page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post"></form>
```

Let's remove the empty form declaration and remove the close form tag immediately after your declaration.  Change those 2 lines to the following:

```
<form name="myForm" action="action_page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
```

It should function a lot more appropriately after those changes.

Answer (score 0):

You had a few issues, as I detailed out in my comment.

1. Targeting the wrong form, `myForm` element was empty. So I changed this accordingly.
2. In your JS, you had `interest` declared but you tried to use variable `shopping` which you did not declare. So I changed that `shopping` to `interest`.

After amending all those mistakes, the code worked.

```js
function validateForm(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); //Pause form from submitting.
   var name = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
   var email = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
   var birthday = document.forms["myForm"]["birthday"].value;

   var interest = document.forms["myForm"]["shopping"].value;
   if (name == "") {
      alert("Name must be filled out");
      return false;
   }
   if (email == "") {
      alert("Email must be filled out");
      return false;
   }
   if (birthday == "") {
      alert("Fill your birthday please");
      return false;
   }
   if (interest == "1") {
      alert("Select your interested thing to do");
      return false;
   }
   
   else event.target.submit(); //submit, all checks were completed
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Busy Bee Florist</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" a href="css/style.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="containers">
      <header>
         <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
      </header>
      <nav>
         <div class="navbar">
            <a href="sign.html">Sign Up For Special Deals!"</a>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            <a href="account.html">Account</a>
            <a href="cart.html">Cart</a>
            <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
               <button class="dropbtn">Colors
               <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
               </button>
               <div class="dropdown-content">
                  <a href="white.html">White</a>
                  <a href="red.html">Red</a>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
               <button class="dropbtn">Occasions
               </button>
               <div class="dropdown-content">
                  <a href="congratulations.html">Congratulations</a>
                  <a href="generic.html">Generic</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="container">
         <h1>Busy Bee Florist</h1>
         <h4> Please Fill Up In the Form</h4>
         <form name="myForm" action="action_page.php" onsubmit="validateForm(event)" method="post">
            <fieldset>
               <legend>Personal Information:</legend>
               Full Name: <input type="text" style="margin-left: 18px;" name="name" placeholder="Your Name"><br><br>
               Email: <input type="email" style="margin-left: 51px;" placeholder="example@gmail.com" name="email"><br><br>
               Date of birth: <input type="date" name="birthday">
            </fieldset>
            <br>
            Which special offers you interest most?<br><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="shopping" value="Shopping"> Lemon Meringue Pie <br><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="shopping" value="Dining"> Respberry Cake <br><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="shopping" value="Dancing"> Bluebarry Muffins<br><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="shopping" value="caramelslice"> Caramel Slice <br><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="shopping" value="cheeryripeslice">Cheery Ripe Slice <br><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="shopping" value="chocolatechip">Chocolate Chip Muffin<br><br>
            <div class="test3"><b>Terms and Condition</b><font color="red"></font></div>
            <div class="test3"> <input type="radio" name="TC" value="agree" >I Agree</div>
            <div class="test3"> <input type="radio" name="TC" value="disagree">I Disagree</div>
            <br><br>
            <div class="w">
               <p>Please provide any additional feedbacks:- </p>
               <br><br>
               <textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="45" placeholder="Please Type Here...."></textarea>
               <br><br>
            </div>
            <br><br>
            <div id="q">
               <button class="btn-submit" value="Submit Reservation" type="submit"> Submit </button>
               <button class="btn-reset" value="Clear Input" type="reset"> Clear Input</button>
            </div>
         </form>
      </div>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```